# Test if a variable contains a value stored in a vector

Tags: r, string, dataframe, testing

I have this following dataframe and vector

```
data=data.frame(var1=c("jup", "far", "part", "part;melt", "rat", "rat;art", "kir;door;art"), var2=c("0","8","5","7;8","3","9;4","6;5;9"))

vec1=c("bato", "kir", "door", "part", "zat", "melt", "art")

> data
          var1  var2
1          jup     0
2          far     8
3         part     5
4    part;melt   7;8
5          rat     3
6      rat;art   9;4
7 kir;door;art 6;5;9
```

i would like to create a third and fourth variable containing the value of var1 and var2 if var1 contains a value stored in vec1. I can do it only if there is only one value in var1 but don't know how to manage with cases containing two values or more.

For example, for "part;melt" I would like to get "part;melt" and "7;8", for "rat;art" I would like to get "art" and "4", for "kir;door;art" I would like to get  "kir;door;art" and "6;5;9"

I will appreciate any help

```
data_output = data %>%
  mutate(var1b=ifelse(var1 %in% vec1, var1, NA)) %>%
 mutate(var2b=ifelse(var1 %in% vec1, var2, NA)) %>%
```

```
> data_output
          var1  var2       var1b var2b
1          jup     0        <NA>  <NA>
2          far     8        <NA>  <NA>
3         part     5        part     5
4    part;melt   7;8   part;melt   7;8
5          rat     3        <NA>  <NA>
6      rat;art   9;4         art     4
7 kir;door;art 6;5;9 kir;dor;art 6;5;9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split semi colon separated data in longer format and use `ifelse` to get the corresponding values.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  separate_longer_delim(c(var1, var2), ";") %>%
  mutate(var1b = ifelse(var1 %in% vec1, var1, NA), 
         var2b = ifelse(var1 %in% vec1, var2, NA)) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with("var"), 
            ~paste0(na.omit(.x), collapse = ";")), .by = row) %>%
  mutate(across(c(var1b, var2b), ~na_if(., ""))) %>%
  select(-row)

#          var1  var2        var1b var2b
#1          jup     0         <NA>  <NA>
#2          far     8         <NA>  <NA>
#3         part     5         part     5
#4    part;melt   7;8    part;melt   7;8
#5          rat     3         <NA>  <NA>
#6      rat;art   9;4          art     4
#7 kir;door;art 6;5;9 kir;door;art 6;5;9
```

Comment: Thank's a lot. My real data were a bit more complicated but it works and using only mutate row, separate_longer_delim and mutate var1b and var2b will help me a lot in the next steps of my analysis.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```r
data %>% 
  mutate(var3 = sapply(lapply(strsplit(var1, ';'), \(x) match(x, vec1)), \(x) {
                  paste(na.omit(vec1[unlist(x)]), collapse = ';')}),
         var4 = unlist(Map(\(x, y) {
           paste(na.omit(x[y %in% vec1]), collapse = ';')}, 
           strsplit(var2, ';'), strsplit(var1, ';'))))
#>           var1  var2         var3  var4
#> 1          jup     0                   
#> 2          far     8                   
#> 3         part     5         part     5
#> 4    part;melt   7;8    part;melt   7;8
#> 5          rat     3                   
#> 6      rat;art   9;4          art     4
#> 7 kir;door;art 6;5;9 kir;door;art 6;5;9
```